# Get value of string between multiple double quotes

Tags: batch-file

i need to extract the int value between the middle quotes of the following string:

```
set str="val="6479695"/>"
echo %str%
```

the value i need is the "6479695".

What i already tried is that: ([Batch - Get string between first and last double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658498/batch-get-string-between-first-and-last-double-quotes))

```
set "new=%str:*"=%
```

But this led me to that error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

It seems that is only work with one double quotes.

can someone help? thanks

Comment: It is clear from your question code that your string is not initially set as shown. Could you please post the actual lines in your code instead of the simplified version you've posted above. I ask because it is very likely that the value can be retrieved in a simpler way prior to this point. Also it looks as if you're reading a line from a file, so if you were to post the content of the file, somebody may be able to provide a solution which grabs the value you want without having to define a value for `str` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is not the [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) syntax by itself but fact that the immediate (`%`) expansion happens before recognition of special characters like the [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) symbol `>`, so after removal of the first `"` (by `%str:*"=%`) the `>` appears outside of a pair of quotation marks.

When you switch to [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) the problem does no longer arise:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str="val="6479695"/>"
echo !str!

set "new=!str:*"=!
echo !new!
endlocal
```

This still does not extract the correct portion of your string, because the remainder `"/>"` is kept. However, this could be removed by something like this (note the `>` which is [escaped](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) by `^` since it appears unquoted):

```cmd
set "new=!new!:"/^>"="
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) with the `"` as delimiter. Since with the normally quoted option string of `for /F` it is not possible to define `"` as delimiter, we use the undocumented unquoted syntax, where we have to escape `=`-signs and <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>:

```cmd
set str="val="6479695"/>"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%I in ("!str!") do set "new=%%I"
echo !new!
endlocal
```

To have the desired value available even past `endlocal`, adapt the code like this:

```cmd
set str="val="6479695"/>"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F tokens^=2^ delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%I in ("!str!") do (
    endlocal & set "new=%%I"
)) || (endlocal & set "new=")
echo/%new%
```

The part behind [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) only executes when the `for /F` loop does not iterate, which is the case when the input string only has got one token; the main purpose of this part is to have `endlocal` also executed in such cases.